# How to get screen resolution from machine that has no screen?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, screen

I am trying to get the screen resolution of a headless machine that is running selenium tests.

Have already tried using `System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen` as well as other options in `Forms`.
I have tried using powershell and c#.  Usually they tell me either the screen size after I RDP into the machine (which is just the size of the remote session) or the requests fail (if I try to get the size from a PSSession).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try >>> `(Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_VideoController).VideoModeDescription` <<<. if you want the specific h&v resolutions, take a look at the other properties of the class. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my issue turned out to be a hardware one and not a software one.
I talked to my IT dept and they told me that they could change the resolution of VMs from their console for Nutanix.  I had no idea that this was the issue.

Make sure to talk to your IT or VM admin if this is the case.  This is the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, the screen class gives you the info you want:

```
$Screen = [system.windows.forms.screen]::AllScreens
"$($Screen.Bounds.Width) $($Screen.Bounds.Height)"
```

Comment: Problem with screen class is that you need a screen.  Trying to use screen class methods  without a screen usually errors out.